# Memory usage of StAX item reader and writer in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, spring-batch

I am using JAXB as a marshaller/unmarshaller to process xml in Spring Batch. How does StaxEventItemReader and StaxEventItemWriter consume memory when reading/writing from/to xml file? Does it store the whole xml size in memory before splitting it into chunks and still uses the same amount of memory throughout the step? Or does it read/write a fragment of the file based on chunk size then releasing the memory usage before processing the next chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StaX](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stax) and [Sax](https://www.baeldung.com/java-sax-parser) both are event-based parser which parses through the XML line by line so it does not store any whole XML file within the memory. This can be an advantage if you have a large XML file and you want to traverse through it. However, if you want to access something in-between then it may not be useful as it does not store anything in memory.

You can also write your own custom context to store the XML elements and its children elements while parsing through the XML file using these libraries so as to store the particular chunk of XML file which you can use and later clear it out when you move to the next event of the XML.

So basically its very efficient as it does not store the whole XML file and it parses through the XML file line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

[StaX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html) means "Streaming API for XML". It parses the XML on-the-fly which means it doesn't hold the whole XML in memory. It is indeed very efficient memory-wise.

`StaxEventItemReader` class is based on *pull-parsing*. See the link for definition of what that means.